# How to remove uncommon columns in two dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes: df1 and df2

df1 has these columns:

```
c1, c2 ,c3 ,c4
```

and df2 has these columns:

```
c2, c3, c4, c5
```

How can I remove the uncommon columns in these 2 dataframes so both become like this:

```
df1: c2, c3, c4
df2: c2, c3, c4
```

Comment: but `df1` does not have column `c5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c2','c3','c4','c5'])
```

*Create* *intersection* of `df1` and `df2` columns name:

```
common_col = (df2.columns) & (df1.columns)
```

*Filter* `df1` and `df2` by `common_col`:

```
df1 = df1[common_col]   # df1.columns: c2, c3, c4
df2 = df2[common_col]   # df2.columns: c2, c3, c4
```

Comment: So you just edited OP's expected output. How are you so sure? I don't think you should do that unless you are 100% sure, which you can't be

Comment: The request was not consistent with the expected output. Now the request and expected output are consistent. If @jdoe wants to ask for more, they can change the question

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to remove c5.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list to store only common columns and then subset columns from the two dataframes

```
# list with only common columns
common_columns = [col for col in df1.columns if col in df2.columns]
# keep only common columns from df1 and df2
df1 = df1[common_columns]
df2 = df2[common_columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent version of pandas has a deprecation warning on the approach above by @Massifox

*FutureWarning: Index.**and** operating as a set operation is deprecated, in the future this will be a logical operation matching Series.**and**.  Use index.intersection(other) instead.*

based on recommendation from deprecation warning, the following worked :

common_columns = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)